TF-IDF for document ranking
I'm working on ranking some news headlines (identical topic) based on how much information is present in them. I've calculated the tf-idf scores for each words in each documents in my corpus. Since I've a vector for each document, I'm not sure what's the best way to aggregate those "word scores" to a "document score".
I maybe wrong here as I don't know if tf-idf scores can be used for rating a document on how much information they contain. If not, what are the other best ways to actually know how much information a document has? I've given some examples of what I mean information.
Examples -

"ABC company, profit increase by 40%" - highly informative
"Best stocks to buy - CD, AB..." - slightly informative
"AB reported says..." - hardly informative

So the information here is comparing these 3 docs and identifying which one has highly relevant/informative words. I'm not focusing on context for my project but open to that as well.
